# Deleting single character on lcd

Tags: arduino, lcd

While I have successfully cleared all the lcd display with the help of some guys here by a cheat code (because it doesn't really cleared the display)`for (int i=0; i < 80; i++)`, Now I needed to delete  **single character** on my lcd display.

*Note:*
I am using serial communication with my [lcd module](http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/images/eterm/E-term.pdf). I intensively search the internet but I could not find any solution, Is there anyone who had an Idea to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The HD44870 command set has no provisions for deleting characters. You will need to read out all the following characters on the display, write them in the appropriate place, and then put one or more blank spaces after.

Comment: @IgnacioVasquez-Abrams Meaning I cant realy delete single character on my lcd?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my example of entering password  with keyboard and displaying it on the LCD:

```
bool enterPassword(char currentPassword[], byte lenghtMaxPassword)
{
    
    byte nextChar = 0;
    char changePassKeyPressed;
  
    while(nextChar <= lenghtMaxPassword)
    {
       changePassKeyPressed = keyboard.getKey();
      
       if(nextChar != lenghtMaxPassword)
       {     

           if(!changePassKeyPressed)
           {
                continue;
           }
           else if(changePassKeyPressed=='#')
           {
                return false; // stop entering the password
           }
           else if(changePassKeyPressed=='*')
           {
                if(nextChar != 0) // Don't try delete char, which is not exists.
                {
                  nextChar--;
                  lcd.setCursor(4 + nextChar,1); 
                  lcd.print(" ");
                  lcd.setCursor(4 + nextChar,1);                  
                }
           }
           else
           {
             lcd.print(changePassKeyPressed);
             currentPassword[nextChar] = changePassKeyPressed;
             nextChar++;
           }
       }
       else
       {
            if(changePassKeyPressed == 'D')
            {
                break;
            }
         
            if(changePassKeyPressed == '#')
            {
                return false;
            }
         
            if(changePassKeyPressed == '*')
            {
                nextChar--;
            }
       }
    }
  
    return true;
   
}
```

Delete a single character you have here...

```
else if(changePassKeyPressed=='*')
{
     if(nextChar != 0) // Don't try delete char, which is not exists.
     {
        nextChar--;
        lcd.setCursor(4 + nextChar,1); 
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(4 + nextChar,1);                  
     }
}
```

When you enable the cursor in the lcd display *lcd.**blink()***, it visually looks like it is actually deleting a character, and in fact you replaced the last character with a space.